# Safari browser back click is not working in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am working on back button click functionality to get the previous page with previous selected filters (like drop-down, date-picker, textbox etc).
 I found code for back click from `backfix.min.js` javascript file.

I tried to save the filter's value in session and read session when user goes back to the previous page.

**Jquery Code:**

```
     bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function () {
                      eval($('.lnkbackClickcls').attr('href'));
                 };

    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbackClick" runat="server" CssClass="lnkbackClickcls" 
OnClick="lnkBack_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

There is a `link button`, which i want to clicked under the back click event but it does not work in safari browser (working in Chrome and Firefox).

**C# Code:**

```
protected void lnkBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (QueryStirng != null || QueryStirng != "")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Flag"] = "1";
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Flag"] = "0";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DataManager.WriteToErrorLog(ex, Path.GetFileName(Request.Path), System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    } 
}
```

Please suggest me something, thanks!!